# The Publisher Could Not Be Verified Startup C#

Tags: c#, startup

I have been making this program for 2 days and a ran into a issue... When i run my program on another computer and restart it, i get a message saying "The Publisher Could Not Be Verified" I want to disable the using regitry. But i dont know how. Any Suggestions or other methods? Here is my code.

```
` using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
            {
                key.SetValue("飪䈚ㄔ", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\"");
            }
            string path = Path.GetTempPath();
            if (File.Exists(path+"䈚ㄔ"))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello", "Windows", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                File.Create(path + "䈚ㄔ");
                string lhol = " ི飪䈚ㄔﾠ㓳 ";

            }`
```

Answer (score 0):

It's recognized as a file from elsewhere, it doesn't have a digital signature.  You're going to get that warning until they turn it off for that file.

Trying to defeat this system is the sort of thing malware does.  If I realized your program did that I would immediately uninstall it.

The legitimate way is a digital signature but the certificates cost money.  It's not something you can do yourself.